# Change a button onclick href based on multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, shopify, selectors-api

I have an order summary.  The order summary is a collection of 5 different HTML IDs based on user selection.  I'm trying to get the "checkout button" to link to different URLs based on different configurations corresponding to different HTML IDs.

For example, if the user selects `"BRAZIL", "2 BAGS", "WHOLE BEAN", "EVERY 4 WEEKS", "ALL ROAST TYPES"` the checkout button would take them to a specific URL and so on specific for that selection. If they make a different selection, they should be taken to a different URL.

I'm assuming a for loop and `if... else` statement would do the trick but I can't seem to figure it out.  I feel like I'm close but maybe I'm way off.

What I currently have:

```js
// CHECKOUT BUTTON CONDITIONALS
function checkoutButton() {
  let checkoutBtnClick = document.querySelectorAll("#change-coffee, #change-bag, #change-grind-type, #change-delivery, #change-roast-type").innerHTML;
  if (checkoutBtnClick === "BRAZIL", "2 BAGS", "WHOLE BEAN", "EVERY 4 WEEKS", "ALL ROAST TYPES") {
    document.getElementById("box-summary-checkout-button").setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href="https://www.google.com/"');
  } else if (checkoutBtnClick === "BRAZIL", "2 BAGS", "GROUND", "EVERY 4 WEEKS", "ALL ROAST TYPES") {
    document.getElementById("box-summary-checkout-button").setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/"');
  }
}
```

```css
/* ORDER SUMMARY */

.container-summary {
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid none;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
}

.box-summary {
  height: 20.5rem;
  width: 30rem;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.box-summary-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .03rem;
  margin-top: 25px;
  color: #433d3d;
  line-height: .95em;
}

.box-summary-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 1rem 3rem;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .03rem;
  line-height: 1.9em;
  color: #393939;
}

.box-summary-block-coffee {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem 4rem;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .03rem;
  line-height: 1.9em;
  color: #393939;
}

.box-summary-option-coffee {
  margin-left: .75rem;
}

.box-summary-block-right {
  text-align: end;
}

.box-summary-category2-left,
.box-summary-category2-right {
  margin-top: .6em;
}

.box-summary-option-bags,
.box-summary-option-grind,
.box-summary-option-delivery,
.box-summary-option-roast,
.box-summary-option-coffee {
  color: #3e718a;
}

.box-summary-shipment-plus-price {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .03rem;
  line-height: .95em;
  color: #433d3d;
}

.box-summary-order-button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box-summary-order-button {
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
  font-size: 15px
}
```

```html
<!--ORDER SUMMARY CONTAINER-->
<div class="container-summary">
  <div class="box-summary">
    <div class="box-summary-title">
      ORDER SUMMARY
    </div>
    <div class="box-summary-block-coffee">
      COFFEE SELECTION: <span class="box-summary-option-coffee" id="change-coffee">BRAZIL</span>
    </div>

    <div class="box-summary-block">
      <div class="box-summary-block-left">
        <div class="box-summary-category1-left">
          # OF BAGS
        </div>
        <div class="box-summary-option-bags" id="change-bag">
          2 BAGS
        </div>
        <div class="box-summary-category2-left">
          GRIND TYPE
        </div>
        <div class="box-summary-option-grind" id="change-grind-type">
          WHOLE BEAN
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box-summary-block-right">
        <div class="box-summary-category1-right">
          DELIVERY
        </div>
        <div class="box-summary-option-delivery" id="change-delivery">
          EVERY 4 WEEKS
        </div>
        <div class="box-summary-category2-right">
          ROAST TYPE
        </div>
        <div class="box-summary-option-roast" id="change-roast-type">
          ALL ROAST TYPES
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="box-summary-order-summary">
      <div class="box-summary-shipment-plus-price">
        <span class="box-summary-price-per-shipment">
                        PRICE PER SHIPMENT:
                    </span>
        <span class="box-summary-order-price" id="box-summary-total-price">
                        $90
                    </span>
      </div>
      <div class="box-summary-order-button-container">
        <button class="box-summary-order-button" id="box-summary-checkout-button" onclick="checkoutButton()">
                        CONTINUE TO CHECKOUT
                    </button>
```

Comment: This is an X/Y problem and I decided to not answer it. It is even very hard to code since you have no logical name or class names to grab each value from.
You are getting to this summary from somewhere. That somewhere needs to stack the options and send the options to ONE url and handle the options there

Comment: You should `console.log(checkoutBtnClick);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for, is something like this :

```
// List Shopify codes for all possible variations as a hierarchical object
let variations = {
  // coffee
  "BRAZIL" : {
    // bag
    "2 BAGS" : {
      // delivery
      "EVERY 4 WEEKS" : {
        // roast type
        "ALL ROAST TYPES" : {
          // grind type
          "WHOLE BEAN" :"42755456106732:1",
          "GROUND" :"42755456106500:1",
          ...
        },
        ...
      },
     ...
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
};

// CHECKOUT BUTTON CONDITIONALS
function checkoutButton() {
  // Select each node you want to process
  let coffee = document.getElementById("change-coffee").innerHTML.trim().toUpperCase();
  let bag = document.getElementById("change-bag").innerHTML.trim().toUpperCase();
  let delivery = document.getElementById("change-delivery").innerHTML.trim().toUpperCase();
  let roastType = document.getElementById("change-roast-type").innerHTML.trim().toUpperCase();
  let grindType = document.getElementById("change-grind-type").innerHTML.trim().toUpperCase();
  
  try {
    // Go find the Shopify code
    // If only grindType is not known, this returns 'undefined'
    // If any of the other values are not known, this triggers an error
    // The order of the variables should match the order in your hierarchical object
    let shopifyCode = variations[coffee][bag][delivery][roastType][grindType];
    if(typeof  shopifyCode === 'undefined') {
      // Now you also throw an error if just grindType is not known
      throw "shopifyCode can't be undefined"; 
    }

    // Build your URL
    const URL = `https://www.server.com/thepartthatstaysthesame/${shopifyCode}`;
    // Display URL in console (useful for testing purposes)
    console.log(URL);
    // Visit the URL you just created
    window.location.href = URL;
  } catch (error) {
    // Do your error handling here
    console.error('Variation unknown');
  }
}
```

Comment: You will have a better result with `nodes.forEach(function(node) { switch (node.textContent.trim()) {` no need to `[].forEach.call`

Comment: @mplungjan : Fair point. A good reason to use `Array.prototype.forEach()` over `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` is the latter not being supported in any version of IE. But since this is 2022, I guess no one really cares about that anymore...

Comment: But you also need to trim to make it work

Comment: @mplungjan : Right... How could I miss that?!... I added a `trim()` call as well as a `toUpperCase()` to ensure the value processed is always uppercase...

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72295375/295783) for a working version which also handles the url not getting  spaces

Comment: @mplungjan : Your code is definitely more elegant than mine, but it isn't particularly readable for JavaScript noobs. I tried to focus on keeping the code as readable & understandable as possible for people with little to no JS experience. Also, I did not want to make any assumptions regarding how exactly the URL should be formed as the OP did not provide sufficient info on that.

Comment: As I said in my first comment I didn't really want to answer since the premise for the existing code was flawed. When OP then accepted your answer, I needed to show how it should be coded. A switch is not something to teach a noob because then everything seems to be solvable with a switch. I cannot remember last time I used a switch. If I look at the receipt, it does not really need a switch. A lookup table perhaps but not a switch

Comment: @mplungjan : Personally, I don't get the bad rep the `switch...case` statement seems to have gotten over the years. IMO it's a perfectly solid & far from inelegant approach when you need to take a specific action depending on the value of one specific variable. And I've used it in production code in this particular context multiple times since I became a professional developer back in 2006, both in JavaScript & other languages.

Comment: @JohnSlegers This approach is really close to what I was trying to accomplish.  However, is there a way to append to the URL based on a group of ID's?  For example, case "BRAZIL", "1 BAG", "WHOLE BEAN" URL += '/appendstringtoURL'. I'm assuming this would be a node list similar to an array?

Comment: @DeanCGiroir : You can process the different nodes in a Nodelist in a way similar to an Array, yes. --- To help you find a better solution for your problem, I'll need more details on the exact logic you want to use to generate a particular URL for different combinations of IDs. How many possible combinations of IDs are there? How should your URL be built for each of the different combinations?

Comment: Hey @johnslegers.  There would be 72 total combinations of IDs (6 Coffee products w/ 12 combinations for each product).  For each combination of IDs there should be a unique URL attached to the CONTINUE TO CHECKOUT button.  This is why I was leaning toward looping through each combination group and using if... else if conditionals to attach the unique URL. Mplungjan was correct in thinking this is just a part of a bigger code.  If you need the whole code let me know but I figured that would be unnecessary.

Comment: @JohnSlegers Also, the reason for needing certain groups of IDs meeting conditions as opposed to individual IDs is because this is custom code for a Shopify store.  You may be familiar with Shopify, but if not, you can create product variants which attach 11-digit numbers to the end of the checkout page URL to track them.  This URL then sends you directly to the checkout page with the unique product variations you've created.  However, the product variants in this instance are a grouping of variations.

Comment: @JohnSlegers Essentially, I'm trying to tell the computer: If the user has "BRAZIL", "1 BAG", "WHOLE BEAN" in there order summary, send them to this unique URL when CONTINUE TO CHECKOUT button is clicked.  If the user has "COLOMBIA", "2 BAG", "WHOLE BEAN" in their order summary, send them to this different URL when CONTINUE TO CHECKOUT button is clicked. And so on, and so on.  Is that clear as mud?  Lol!

Comment: @DeanCGiroir : No it's not clear at all. You're much too vague. Please elaborate on the "so on and so on" part. Please explain how each URL corresponds to each diferent combination of IDs.

Comment: @JohnSlegers From your code, is there a way to 

`switch (normalized) {
      case "BRAZIL", "2 BAGS", "WHOLE BEAN", "ALL ROAST TYPES":
        // Append specific string to URL
        URL += '42755456106732:1'
        break;
switch (normalized) {
      case "BRAZIL", "2 BAGS", "GROUND", "ALL ROAST TYPES":
        // Append specific string to URL
        URL += '42755456106500:1'
        break;`
Notice the change in URL for the different order summary combinations.  Can this be done for any number of combinations?

Comment: @DeanCGiroir : There's multiple ways to achieve this, some being better than others.

Comment: @DeanCGiroir : OK, so I just noticed I missed a few of your comments from yesterday. I think I know what you're going for and update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you. However, how would you add the other variations to this? The "Whole Bean" and "Ground" variations work but I don't understand how to add the other 70 variations. For example, how would you add a "1 BAG" variation to your solution? Also, could all 72 variations be created inside let = variations variable?

Comment: @DeanCGiroir : Well, this is why I kept asking for more details on how each URL corresponds with different variations. It would be clearer with more than two options. But yes, you should just add all 72 variations to your `variations´ variable, adhering to the current hierarchy. So, first add all your different opties for "coffee". For each of those, add the different options for "bag". For each of those, add the different options for "delivery". etc. And at the deepest level, add your corresponding Shopify code.

Comment: @JohnSlegers Got it. Thank you for taking time out of your day(s) to provide a solution for me. I greatly appreciate it. I'm sure trying to get a noob to understand can be frustrating at times but just know you've taught me a lot in solving my problem. You stuck in there with me.  Thank you sir.

Comment: @DeanCGiroir : You're welcome. I'm glad I was able to make a difference. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map.

Also recommended to use addEventListener

Note the spread operator `[...]` to make an array of the node list to map

I also assume the IDs we are looking for all start with `change`

```js
// CHECKOUT BUTTON CONDITIONALS
document.getElementById("box-summary-checkout-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const parms = [...document.querySelectorAll("[id^=change]")]
    .map(div => `${div.id}=${div.textContent.trim().replace(/ /g,"+")}`);
  const url = `https://www.server.com/someprocesses?${parms.join("&")}`;
  console.log(url);
  //window.location.href = url;

})
```

```css
/* ORDER SUMMARY */

.container-summary {
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid none;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
}

.box-summary {
  height: 20.5rem;
  width: 30rem;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.box-summary-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .03rem;
  margin-top: 25px;
  color: #433d3d;
  line-height: .95em;
}

.box-summary-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 1rem 3rem;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .03rem;
  line-height: 1.9em;
  color: #393939;
}

.box-summary-block-coffee {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem 4rem;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .03rem;
  line-height: 1.9em;
  color: #393939;
}

.box-summary-option-coffee {
  margin-left: .75rem;
}

.box-summary-block-right {
  text-align: end;
}

.box-summary-category2-left,
.box-summary-category2-right {
  margin-top: .6em;
}

.box-summary-option-bags,
.box-summary-option-grind,
.box-summary-option-delivery,
.box-summary-option-roast,
.box-summary-option-coffee {
  color: #3e718a;
}

.box-summary-shipment-plus-price {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .03rem;
  line-height: .95em;
  color: #433d3d;
}

.box-summary-order-button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box-summary-order-button {
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
  font-size: 15px
}
```

```html
<!--ORDER SUMMARY CONTAINER-->
<div class="container-summary">
  <div class="box-summary">
    <div class="box-summary-title">
      ORDER SUMMARY
    </div>
    <div class="box-summary-block-coffee">
      COFFEE SELECTION: <span class="box-summary-option-coffee" id="change-coffee">BRAZIL</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box-summary-block">
      <div class="box-summary-block-left">
        <div class="box-summary-category1-left">
          # OF BAGS
        </div>
        <div class="box-summary-option-bags" id="change-bag">
          2 BAGS
        </div>
        <div class="box-summary-category2-left">
          GRIND TYPE
        </div>
        <div class="box-summary-option-grind" id="change-grind-type">
          WHOLE BEAN
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-summary-block-right">
        <div class="box-summary-category1-right">
          DELIVERY
        </div>
        <div class="box-summary-option-delivery" id="change-delivery">
          EVERY 4 WEEKS
        </div>
        <div class="box-summary-category2-right">
          ROAST TYPE
        </div>
        <div class="box-summary-option-roast" id="change-roast-type">
          ALL ROAST TYPES
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="box-summary-order-summary">
      <div class="box-summary-shipment-plus-price">
        <span class="box-summary-price-per-shipment">
                        PRICE PER SHIPMENT:
                    </span>
        <span class="box-summary-order-price" id="box-summary-total-price">
                        $90
                    </span>
      </div>
      <div class="box-summary-order-button-container">
        <button class="box-summary-order-button" id="box-summary-checkout-button">
                        CONTINUE TO CHECKOUT
                    </button>
```